# Google PLaces api -INVALID REQUEST

Tags: google-places-api

While creating a location based service using google api and google app engine (python) when the request is forwarded i get the following the error as the output

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

The url and required parameters seems fine as per the documentation. Still not able to get it correct. Please help. Thanks....

```
import webapp2

    MAIN_PAGE_HTML="""\

    <html> 
     <head> 
      <title> Goole location based services</title>
      </head>
      <body bgcolor="Cyan" text="Brown"> 
       <h1 align="center"> Welcome</h1> <br> <hr>
       <br> 
         <h3 align="center">Please enter the following details to get the sugestions.</h3>
         <br>
         <hr>

         <form name="form1" action ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json" method="get">
         <p> Enter Query : <input type="text" name="Query"><br>
             <input type="hidden" name="sensor" value="true">
             <input type="hidden" name="key" value="myKey">
             <input type="Submit" name="btnsubmit" value="submit">
             </p>
             </form>
             </body>
             </html>

             """

    class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_HTML)


    application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                          ('/',MainPage),
                                          ],debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you share the actual request URL?  You can get this from the Network tab in your browser's developer console.  And are you sending an actual developer key, or just the string "mykey"?

Comment: nope i am sending my developer key provivded to me by google.

Comment: Please share your actual request URL (you can blank out the key), or otherwise we can't help you debug this.